# Who are the low-bit and high-bit users?

Tags: wireless

I am currently studying UMTS where Beam-forming antenna release(?) beam for low-bit users and high-bit users.

Who are those low bit and high bit users? As I understand it, the low and high bit devices, always sniff or find signal that matches their bit requirements? Correct my understanding.